# How can I stop emacs from highlighting whitespace?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, whitespace

After a recent update, my Perl files are rendered like this:

[image: example of an emacs window showing highlighted whitespace]

Note that trailing spaces are shown in red and empty lines in yellow. This is happening despite my having the following in my `~/.emacs`:

```
(setq cperl-invalid-face nil)
(setq sp-highlight-pair-overlay nil)
```

This does not seem to be related to anything in my `~/.emacs` or `~/.emacs.d/init.el` files since renaming them and launching emacs still shows the same behavior. However, the problem is not there if I launch with `emacs -Q`. In case they are relevant, here are my [`.emacs`](http://pastebin.com/zp3TAEuC) and [`.init.el`](http://pastebin.com/XYcRku7J) files. Finally, I also tried launching emacs as a different user and had the same issue so it seems to be a site-wide problem.

I get the same behavior in Elisp, C and Perl/CPerl modes but not in Fundamental or shell modes. How can I remove this highlighting?

I am running emacs 24.4.1 on Debian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should generally start Emacs with `emacs -q` to make sure it's not your configuration.  If that doesn't get rid of it, but `emacs -Q` does, chances are it's the way your Emacs was packaged or a site file that's used for every user on your system.

Additionally to that you can inspect the faces involved by placing point at the highlighted area and doing `M-x describe-char`.  This will tell you what functionality is responsible for the highlighting.

Comment: As always... If your init file is problematic, recursively bisect it by commenting out sections until you find the problematic piece. Use `comment-region` to comment (or with `C-u` uncomment) the region. Comment out 1/2, then 3/4, 7/8,... until you find exactly which tiny bit is causing the problem. Very quick to do.

Comment: `M-;` is a quicker alternative to `M-x comment-region` https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Comment-Commands.html (not perfectly equivalent, but close enough for most purposes)

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is absolutely right. I am posting this to specify which file was the issue for me. After noticing that the problem persisted with `emacs -q` but gone with `emacs --no-site-file`, I checked the files in `/etc/emacs/site-start.d`. After sequentially deleting each of them and launching `emacs`, I found that the culprit on my Debian system, running 24.4.1, was

```
/etc/emacs/site-start.d/50develock-el.el
```

This file in turn loads `/usr/share/emacs24/site-lisp/develock-el/develock.el` and that's where the whitespace highlighting was being set.

I solved it by simply commenting out all lines from `/etc/emacs/site-start.d/50develock-el.el`. This is not very elegant and a better way would be to disable the specific features that annoy me in `/usr/share/emacs24/site-lisp/develock-el/develock.el` but that is beyond my ken. So far, this brute force approach seems to be working.

Comment: Sounds like it's the Debian [develock-el](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/develock-el) package you should be able to remove with your package manager.  If that's possible and solves your problem, report a bug with that package because a package enabling itself is generally considered a bug.

Comment: Why not just look for where `whitespace-mode` is enabled and comment out that one-liner (taking care, of course, to not comment out any closing parentheses of a prior section)?  It is either `(whitespace-mode . . .)` or `(global-whitespace-mode . . .`

Comment: @lawlist because there are several dozen (perhaps a hundred) cases of whitespace in that file and I don't have the knowledge or patience to go through them. And it seems to have nothing to do with `whitespace-mode`. I don't use that as far as I know and it is not mentioned anywhere in `develock.el`.

Comment: After looking at the source-code http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DevelockMode there does not appear to be an easy method of turning it off except to prevent it from loading.  And, you are correct, it is not `whitespace-mode`.

Comment: I applied Terdon's fix, blunt as it is.  Shouldn't there be a way to turn develock off in .emacs?

Answer (score 1):

Like wasamasa suggested, put the cursor on the character or highlighted area and do

`M-x describe-char`

Suppose the face is "whitespace-empty" (I was looking to get rid of the yellow highlight)

```
(custom-set-faces
  '(whitespace-empty ((t (:background "grey20" :foreground "gray30"))))
)
```

in your `~/.emacs` file.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by commenting out:

```
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook
      (lambda () (interactive)
        (setq show-trailing-whitespace 1)))
```

in the file `~/.emacs.d/custom/setup-general.el`